# Using regex and converting usernames in Twitter to "usrusr" token

Tags: python, regex, pandas, twitter

I need to find Twitter usernames in a dataframe and convert the usernames to “usrusr” token for ethical reasons. I tried this code:

```
def finduser(string):
    regex = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]))@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)"
    username = (regex,string)
    return["usrusr" for x in username]

def finduserinrow(row):
    return finduser(row['text'])

annotated['new column'] = annotated.apply(finduserinrow, axis=1)
annotated.head()
```

But it converts all the cells in the `new column` to `[usrusr, usrusr]`. But I want that tweet texts stay there as it were and only usernames in that tweets need to be converted to `usrusr` token. How can I fix this problem? Any ideas, any help?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
import re
#...
def finduser(string):
    return re.sub(r"(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])@[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+", "usrusr", string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lJIqpd/1).

It seems that the Pandas code you can use is

```py
annotated['new column'] = annotated['text'].str.replace(r'(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])@[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+', 'usrusr')
```

*Regex details*:

- `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])` - immediately to the left of the current location, there can be no ASCII letter, digit, `_`, `.` or `-`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z]+` - one or more uppercase  ASCII letters
- `[A-Za-z0-9_-]+`  - one or more ASCII letters, digits, `_` and `-` chars.

See a Pandas test using your current code:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'text':['abc 12 @Sasha, @Vasya etc.', '@KnowWho...'],'text2':['abc 12 @Sasha, @Vasya etc.', '@KnowWho...']})
>>> df
                         text                       text2
0  abc 12 @Sasha, @Vasya etc.  abc 12 @Sasha, @Vasya etc.
1                 @KnowWho...                 @KnowWho...
>>> import re

>>> def finduserinrow(row):
    return finduser(row['text'])

>>> def finduser(string):
    return re.sub(r"(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_.-])@([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)", "usrusr", string)

>>> df.apply(finduserinrow, axis=1)
0    abc 12 usrusr, usrusr etc.
1                     usrusr...
dtype: object
```